# Python: CircularQueue print items from begin to end of Queue can't figure out how to do the __str-- function

Tags: python

I am trying to implement Circular Queue in python and trying implement str(self) that print all the elements from the queue from the beginning to the end.When I print out the list, it does not give the whole list of items in the queue.

I am splicing the items from the self.items from the front and going till the end of the list.

```py
class CircularQueue:

    def __init__(self, capacity):
        self.items = [None] * capacity
        self.max_queue = capacity
        self.front = 0
        self.back = self.max_queue - 1
        self.count = 0

    def enqueue(self, item):
        if not self.is_full():
            self.back = (self.back + 1) % self.max_queue
            self.items[self.back] = item
            self.count += 1

    def dequeue(self):
        if not self.is_empty():
            item = self.items[self.front]
            self.front = (self.front + 1) % self.max_queue
            self.count -= 1
            return item

    def is_full(self):
        return self.count == self.max_queue

    def is_empty(self):
        return self.count == 0

    def peek(self):
        return self.items[self.front]
    def __str__(self):
        my_list = []
        for i in self.items[self.front:]:
            my_list.append(i)

        for i in self.items[:self.back+1]:
            my_list.append(i)

        return str(my_list)


q = CircularQueue(4)
print(q)
q.enqueue(1)
q.enqueue(2)
print(q)
q.enqueue(3)
q.enqueue(4)
print(q)

expected result
-> || ->
-> |1, 2| ->
-> |1, 2, 3, 4| ->

got
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
[1, 2, None, None, 1, 2]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]

q = CircularQueue(4)
q.enqueue(1)
q.enqueue(2)
q.enqueue(3)
q.enqueue(4)
q.dequeue()
q.dequeue()
print(q)
q.dequeue()
q.dequeue()
print(q)

expected result
-> |3, 4| ->
-> || ->

got
[3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You added two similar for loops, it's just that the first for loop prints everything on the right of the front, and the second for loop prints everything on the left of the back/rear. For example, if we have [1,2,None,None] where the front is at index 0 (value=1) and the rear is at index 1 (value=2) the 2 loops will print out [1,2,None,None,1,2], p.s the code adds 1 to the rear when printing, that's why you get [1,2,None,None,1,2] and not [1,2,None,None,1]

Solution:
replace the 2 for loops with 1 for loop that goes through the elements of the list once, so no splicing is needed

For the second output, I noticed that the dequeue function doesn't do anything, so I made it so that it replaces the item in the front with None

I added # changed on the lines I changed

```
class CircularQueue:

    def __init__(self, capacity):
        self.items = [None] * capacity
        self.max_queue = capacity
        self.front = 0
        self.back = self.max_queue - 1
        self.count = 0

    def enqueue(self, item):
        if not self.is_full():
            self.back = (self.back + 1) % self.max_queue
            self.items[self.back] = item
            self.count += 1

    def dequeue(self):
        if not self.is_empty():
            self.items[self.front] = None   # changed
            self.front = (self.front + 1) % self.max_queue
            self.count -= 1

    def is_full(self):
        return self.count == self.max_queue

    def is_empty(self):
        return self.count == 0

    def peek(self):
        return self.items[self.front]
    def __str__(self):
        my_list = []
        for i in self.items:    # changed
            my_list.append(i)

        return str(my_list)
```